# Does the Shockley Ideal diode equation involve drift current?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I've encountered a contradiction in semiconductors.

The ideal diode equation considers saturation current (the current when applied voltage is reverse biased to the diode). I thought that saturation current was due to drift.

However, on the other hand, the derivation of the Schockly ideal diode equation assumes **no drift current** in the transport equation. See here: https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solving-for-quasi-neutral-regions

Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saturation current is diffusion current, not drift. It is minority carrier diffusion current.

Comment: doesn't this question say it's due to drift? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129035/what-is-reverse-saturation-current

Comment: @Goldname - There was a comment under that question mentioning that should be diffusion, not drift. Keep in mind that the people asking the questions are not necessarily going to use all of the right terms.

Comment: My mistake. I had also erroneously myself thought that was the case.